# First Exception which isn't a PropagatedCacheException

Tags: java, caching

Cache2k wraps Exceptions in a PropagatedCacheException as mentioned in the [apidocs](http://cache2k.org/cache2k-api/apidocs/index.html?org/cache2k/PropagatedCacheException.html).
This leads to multiple layers of PropagatedCacheExceptions I need to unwrap in order to get to the first meaningful cause.

```
try {
  // some long Exceptionchain is thrown
} catch (Throwable e) {
   while (e.getCause() instanceof PropagatedCacheException) {
      e = e.getCause();
   }
   Throwable rootCause = e.getCause();
}
```

is there a better a better way to do this, or am I missing some API like `public Throwable getFirstCause()` which may be documented elsewhere? I found [Throwables.getRootCause()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Throwables.html#getRootCause%28java.lang.Throwable%29), but that's not what I am looking for, as I don't want the innermost Exception.

Answer (score 0):

There already is a pretty similar issue on Github. Seems like there is and will not be an API for this. [Issue #14](https://github.com/headissue/cache2k/issues/14)